# Formula for $r+2r^2+3r^3+...+nr^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

Is there a formula to get $r+2r^2+3r^3+\dots+nr^n$ provided that $|r|<1$?  This seems like the geometric "sum" $r+r^2+\dots+r^n$ so I guess that we have to use some kind of trick to get it, but I cannot think of a single one.  Can you please help me with this problem?

Comment: If you take it to infinity then yes.

Comment: This is surely a duplicate.

Comment: @Gamamal There is a well-known formula for the finite sum, too.

Comment: You know the sum of a finite geometric progression. Differentiate and multiply by $r$

Comment: $\large S_n=\frac{r^{n+1}-r}{r-1}+rS_{n-1}$ or like this

Comment: Another way: Knowing that $(n+2)-2(n+1)+(n)=0$, calculate $S-2S+S$ in a clever way.

Comment: Divide by $r$ and see the relation between the terms $kr^k$ and $(k-1)r^{k}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have
$$1+r+r^2 + \cdots + r^n = \dfrac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}$$
Differentiating this once, we obtain
$$1+2r + 3r^2 + \cdots + nr^{n-1}= \dfrac{nr^{n+1}-(n+1)r^n + 1}{(r-1)^2}$$
Multiply the above by $r$ to obtain what you want.

Comment: Note that this works even if $|r| \ge 1$

Answer (score 8):

HINT: $r+2r^2+3r^3+... +nr^n=(r+r^2+\dots+r^n)+(r^2+r^3+\dots+r^n)+\dots+(r^n)$ and compute values in parentheses.

Comment: Oh dayum, this is nice.

Comment: @Gamamal Thank you! Without differentiation it is possible to understand on a lower level of mathematical education.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k r^k = r\sum_{k=1}^n k r^{k-1} = r\left(\sum_{k=1}^n r^{k}\right)^\prime = r\left(r\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}\right)^\prime
$$

Answer (score 0):

What I am thinking of is this: $$r+2r^2+3r^3+...+nr^n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}r^k + \sum_{k=2}^nr^k + ... \sum_{k=n}^nr^k$$
Each is a geometric series, so the sum would be $$\frac{1-r^n}{1-r} + r\frac{1-r^{n-1}}{1-r} + ... + r^n$$.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}r+2r^2+3r^3+\ldots+nr^n&=r(1+2r+3r^2+\ldots+nr^{n-1})=r(1+r+r^2+\dots+r^n)'\\&=r\biggl(\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}\biggl)'=r\,\frac{nr^{n+1}-(n+1)r^n+1}{(1-r)^2}.
\end{align*}